# Could not load file or assembly Owin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Owin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Comment: I suspect that you have a reference in your Web.config file to the 'Owin'... remove it and re-query your ASP.NET MVC application

Comment: i have no reference for owin.dll in my web config file . I have reference of Microsoft.Owin,Microsoft.Owin.Security,Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies,Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth in web.config

Comment: Check that all of the references to these dlls in your web.config are also actual dependencies within your project too.  If they're not then they can be deleted out of the web.config.

Comment: I removed there 3 Microsoft.Owin.Security,Microsoft.Owin.Securi‌​ty.Cookies,Microsoft‌​.Owin.Security.OAuth from web config and referencing as they were not used , but still I am facing same issue

Comment: Hey got the solution actually my bad mine project name was also Owin ;-) Thnks

Comment: Glad that you found the solution.  You can probably delete this question a  I doubt that it will be useful to anyone >.<

Comment: It won't be.  The question provides zero information aside from the error message itself.

Comment: Hey, Thanks @AbhinavGoyal , you save my day LOL